# r - within-subject winsorization

Tags: r, outliers, desctools

I have a long-format dataframe `data.set`, in which each subject has different numeric values (`data.set$target_resp.rt`) per conditions. I have already winsorized my data with respect to an overall criterion by using the DescTool function `Winsorize` (see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DescTools/versions/0.99.19/topics/Winsorize) for info):

```
overall.criterion.2sd <- data.set$overall.mean+(2*data.set$overall.sd)
winsors.2 <- DescTools::Winsorize(data.set$target_resp.rt, maxval=overall.criterion.2sd[1])
```

Above, it was possible to define `maxval` as the first value of the variable `overall.criterion.2sd`, as it's the same values for all subjects. Now I would like to winsorize my data by subject, i.e. I'll need to run within-subject row-by-row winsorizisation. Here's my attempt, with `criterion.2sd` is just a vector of *N* values (*N*=no. of subjects):

```
criterion.2sd <- data.set$rt.mean+(2*data.set$rt.sd)
within.winsors.2 <- data.set %>% group_by(Nome, Cognome) %>%
                                    Winsorize(data.set$target_resp.rt, maxval=unique(criterion.2sd))
```

The following error pops up:

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, x < minval, value =
>   c(1.35768795013,  :    'value' is the wrong length

I understand that something is wrong the cardinality of the `maxval` variable, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Can anybody help?

Here's a sample of the dataset `data.set` (hopefully it's enough; let me know if it's the right format):

```
   subject        target_resp.rt   rt.mean     rt.sd
 1 1              1.0398901        0.9016781   0.3109358
 2 1              0.6887729        0.9016781   0.3109358
 3 1              0.7691720        0.9016781   0.3109358
 4 1              1.0064900        0.9016781   0.3109358
 5 1              0.8195999        0.9016781   0.3109358
 6 2              0.8410320        1.0500845   0.4210796
 7 2              0.8229311        1.0500845   0.4210796
 8 2              0.9250839        1.0500845   0.4210796
 9 2              1.0085750        1.0500845   0.4210796
10 2              1.1406291        1.0500845   0.4210796
11 3              0.5561039        0.749789    0.2350127
12 3              0.6022139        0.749789    0.2350127
13 3              0.8560688        0.749789    0.2350127
14 3              0.5886030        0.749789    0.2350127
15 3              0.5520449        0.749789    0.2350127
```

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset for us to test? There's probably a simple fix, because `group_by` usually takes care of situations like this.

Comment: I posted it above! many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with mixed up dplyr syntax. In the original question, you're passing a vector to `Winsorize`, but `data.set %>% group_by(Nome, Cognome)` is a dataset and the pipe (`%>%`) passes the whole dataset to the first argument of `Winsorize`, meaning you're really calling

```
Winsorize(x = data.set, minval = ..., maxval = ...)
```

What you really want is to use `mutate` after the `group_by` to change `target_resp.rt`; the syntax looks like:

```
data.set %>% group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(target_winsorized = Winsorize(target_resp.rt, maxval=unique(overall.criterion.2sd))
```

That creates a new variable in the dataset `target_winsorized` with the properties you want. In the future you might also want to save the `overall.criterion.2sd` inside the dataset too.

## Docs

Check out the `dplyr` docs if want to learn more about syntax and `dplyr` style.